# Accidentally deleted status.cgi in my nagios cgi folder

Tags: patch, nagios

Can anyone tell me how to recreate my status.cgi file for nagios. I have a status.dat file that supposedly it is created from. Bonus points if you can tell me how to make a status-json.cgi file also.

I have downloaded the status.c file from nagios 3.5.0 and also the Makefile that was in the same cgi folder. However when I tried copying those to my server and running the command "make status.cgi" I got "no rule to make target 'status'. Stop.

SOLVED:

Recreating just the status.cgi file proved difficult and trivial. What I did to get the file back was this.

1. I created a copy of my whole /usr/local directory just to have a
   backup.
2. I downloaded the source for a new full install of nagios for the specific version I had installed.
3. ./configure
4. make all
5. make install <- this recreates all the cgi files.
6. I then recopied my original local directory back (changing the name of the one I just made)
7. Then moved the status.cgi file from the new local directory to the original one (in /usr/local/nagios/sbin)

the status.cgi file is now working again

Comment: Why not just extract it from whatever binary package your distribution installed it from?

Comment: Thats what I did. I extracted status.c file. Typically when installing Nagios you run 'make all', and that turns status.c into status.cgi but 'make all' doesn't work for me.

Comment: No, I am talking about *binaries*, you are talking about source files and Makefiles. Did you install Nagios from source last time? What distribution do you run?

Comment: I originally tried copying the binary from another place but it said configurations were invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you need the command:

make install-webconf

That'll recreate the files and drop them where they need to be

Comment: make install-webconf does not solve this problem, it just reconfigures the web configuration files which actually removed my password and caused a second headache that I had to fix with this:
htpasswd -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin

make all -> make install was what I was looking for. But those two commands would not work without all the source files.